# Deleting pandas dataframe rows if value in given column not contained in a list

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have pandas dataframe called `df` that contains several columns and a `df['MY STATE']` column. My goal is to remove all the rows from the dataframe which to not contains US states. I want to do this by comparing the value in the cell to a pandas series I have containing all the state abbreviations. I have seen people use something like the following to clean a dataframe:

```
df = df[df['COST'] <= 0]
```

But something like what I need (below) doesn't work

```
df = df[df['MY STATE'] not in states['Abbreviation'].values]
```

Is there a way to do this simply?

I have read that `df.query()` can be used to do something like this, but I have not yet found an example, and have also read that `df.query()` cannot be used when there is a space in the name of the column.

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverse operator `~`:

```
df = df[~df['MY STATE'].isin(states['Abbreviation'].values)]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. When I implemented it, however, I noticed that some of the rows don't contain values or are 'nan'. Can I modify this to also keep those rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you add sample of data? Maybe 5-6 rows, please add problematic rows too. Thanks. You can modify this dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'MY STATE':['a','b','',np.nan],
                   'B':[4,5,6,5], 
                   'C':[7,8,9,7]})
` And what is `states['Abbreviation']` ? `Series` or `dict`?

Comment: Actually, in the spirit of Stack Exchange, I should probably keep this on topic, and ask that as a separate question if I can't figure it out. I thought it might be short, quick modification. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. It is up to you, but obviously is better create new question. Small advice - dont forget add sample of data, desired output and your code (what you try), then is more easier answering.  Good luck!